# Update Side menu after logging in ionic 5

Tags: angularjs, ionic5

I have to update the data in sidemenu after user logs in. I'm using Ionic 5. This is my app.component.ts which has the side menu.

```
   import { Component, OnInit, Inject, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
   import { Router } from '@angular/router';
   import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
   import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
   import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
   import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
   
   import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
   import { APP_CONFIG, AppConfig } from './app.config';
   import { MyEvent } from 'src/services/myevent.services';
   import { Constants } from 'src/models/contants.models';
   import { ApisService } from 'src/app/services/apis.service';
   import { UtilService } from 'src/app/services/util.service';
   import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
   
   
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
   })
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
     rtlSide = "left";
     showLogout:any=false;
     username: any;
     userno: any; 
     public selectedIndex = 0;
     public appPages = [
       {
         title: 'Home',
         sub_title: 'Yummy Foods',
         url: '/home',
         icon: 'zmdi zmdi-store ion-text-start'
       },
       {
         title: 'My Orders',
         sub_title: 'Foods to your tummy',
         url: '/myorders',
         icon: 'zmdi zmdi-cutlery ion-text-start'
       },
       {
         title: 'My Profile',
         sub_title: 'Who am i?',
         url: '/myprofile',
         icon: 'zmdi zmdi-pin-account ion-text-start'
       },
       {
         title: 'Reviews',
         sub_title: 'Hows food?',
         url: '/review',
         icon: 'zmdi zmdi-ticket-star ion-text-start'
       },
       {
         title: 'Contact Us',
         sub_title: 'Let us know your queries and feedbacks',
         url: '/contact',
         icon: 'zmdi zmdi-comment-text ion-text-start'
       },
       {
         title: 'Exit',
         sub_title: 'Come back soon',
         icon: 'zmdi zmdi-alert-triangle ion-text-start'
       }
     ];
   
     constructor(
       @Inject(APP_CONFIG) public config: AppConfig,
       private platform: Platform, private navCtrl: NavController,
       private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
       private statusBar: StatusBar,
       private ngZone: NgZone,
       private util: UtilService,
       private apis: ApisService,
       private translate: TranslateService, private myEvent: MyEvent) {
       this.initializeApp();
       this.myEvent.getLanguageObservable().subscribe(value => {
         this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(['./']);
         this.globalize(value);
       });
     }
   
     loadProfile() {
       this.apis.checkAuth().then((user) => {
         if (user) {
          this.getProfile();
         }
       }).catch(error => {
         console.log(error);
       });
     }
   
     
   
     initializeApp() {
       this.platform.ready().then(() => {
         this.statusBar.styleDefault();
         this.splashScreen.hide();
   
         let defaultLang = window.localStorage.getItem(Constants.KEY_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE);
         this.globalize(defaultLang);
       });
     }
   
     globalize(languagePriority) {
       this.translate.setDefaultLang("en");
       let defaultLangCode = this.config.availableLanguages[0].code;
       this.translate.use(languagePriority && languagePriority.length ? languagePriority : defaultLangCode);
       this.setDirectionAccordingly(languagePriority && languagePriority.length ? languagePriority : defaultLangCode);
     }
   
     setDirectionAccordingly(lang: string) {
       switch (lang) {
         case 'ar': {
           this.rtlSide = "rtl";
           break;
         }
         default: {
           this.rtlSide = "ltr";
           break;
         }
       }
     }
   
     ngOnInit() {
       const path = window.location.pathname.split('folder/')[1];
       if (path !== undefined) {
         this.selectedIndex = this.appPages.findIndex(page => page.title.toLowerCase() === path.toLowerCase());
       }
       this.getProfile();
       
     }
   
     ionViewWillEnter() {
       this.getProfile();
     }
   
     ionViewDidLoad()
     {
       this.getProfile();
     }
   
     my_profile() {
       this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(['./myprofile']);
     }
   
     getProfile() {
       this.apis.getMyProfile(localStorage.getItem('uid')).then((data: any) => {
         console.log('userdata', data);
         if (data) {
           this.ngZone.run(() => {
             this.username = data.fullname;
             this.userno = data.phone;
           });
           
         }
       }).catch(error => {
         console.log(error);
       });
     }
   
   }
```

I need to update name and phone number in side menu after user logs in. This is the login method in signin.page.ts

```
       onLogin(form: NgForm) {
       console.log('form', form);
       this.submitted = true;
       if (form.valid) {
         const emailfilter = /^[\w._-]+[+]?[\w._-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;
         if (!emailfilter.test(this.login.email)) {
           this.util.showToast(this.util.translate('Please enter valid email'), 'danger', 'bottom');
           return false;
         }
         console.log('login');
         this.isLogin = true;
         this.api.login(this.login.email, this.login.password).then((userData) => {
           console.log(userData);
           this.api.getProfile(userData.uid).then((info) => {
             console.log(info);
             if (info && info.status === 'active') {
               localStorage.setItem('uid', userData.uid);
               localStorage.setItem('help', userData.uid);
               localStorage.setItem('uname', userData.fullname);
               localStorage.setItem('unumber', userData.phone);
               this.isLogin = false;
               this.util.publishLoggedIn('LoggedIn');
               // this.navCtrl.back();
               this.router.navigate(['home']);
             } else {
               Swal.fire({
                 title: this.util.translate('Error'),
                 text: this.util.translate('Your are blocked please contact administrator'),
                 icon: 'error',
                 showConfirmButton: true,
                 showCancelButton: true,
                 confirmButtonText: this.util.translate('Need Help?'),
                 backdrop: false,
                 background: 'white'
               }).then(data => {
                 if (data && data.value) {
                   localStorage.setItem('help', userData.uid);
                   this.router.navigate(['inbox']);
                 }
               });
             }
           }).catch(err => {
             console.log(err);
             this.util.showToast(`${err}`, 'danger', 'bottom');
           });
         }).catch(err => {
           if (err) {
             console.log(err);
             this.util.showToast(`${err}`, 'danger', 'bottom');
           }
         }).then(el => this.isLogin = false);
       }
     }
```

I thought of using events but in ionic 5 events API is deprecated. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I used Behaviour Subject to achieve this. In my Service class i have a class AuthInfo.

```
    export class AuthInfo {
       constructor(public $uid: string) { }

   isLoggedIn() {
    return !!this.$uid;
  }
}
```

Then i declare a variable for unknown user and a behaviour subject variable

```
         static UNKNOWN_USER = new AuthInfo(null);
      public authInfo$: BehaviorSubject<AuthInfo> = new BehaviorSubject<AuthInfo>(ApisService.UNKNOWN_USER);
```

And then here goes the method for logging in a user:

```
   public login(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
      return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.fireAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(res => {
            if (res.user) {
              this.db.collection('users').doc(res.user.uid).update({
                fcm_token: localStorage.getItem('fcm') ? localStorage.getItem('fcm') : ''
              });
              this.authInfo$.next(new AuthInfo(res.user.uid));
              resolve(res.user);
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
   
            this.authInfo$.next(ApisService.UNKNOWN_USER);
            reject(`login failed ${err}`);
          });
      });
    }
```

Finally in app.component.ts file's ngOnInit method,

```
    this.apis.authInfo$.subscribe((data) => {
         console.log('userData',data);
         this.userID = data.$uid;
         console.log('Userd id from behaviour subject', this.userID);
         this.loadProfile();
         console.log("called get profile after behaviour subject");
     });
```

this updates the data in side menu in realtime